# Find unknown array key in php?

Tags: php

I have an array

```
$array = array (
  'pubMessages' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'msg' => 'Not bad',
      'type' => 'warning',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'msg' => 'Bad',
      'type' => 'error',
    ),
  ),
);
```

To remove the sub array having 'type' => 'error', I use bellow code

```
$key = array_search('error', $array);
unset($array["pubMessages"][$key]);
```

The key name of the array **pubMessages** is changed every time, please tell me how to get this key name dynamically?
The count of arrays in pubMessages is also variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get dynamic key name using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and then loop through inner array and check if key `type` is equal to `error` remove it.

```
$dynamicKey = array_keys($array)[0];
foreach($array[$dynamicKey] as $item){
    if ($item['type'] == 'error')
        unset($array[$dynamicKey][$key]);
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/b3c1d)

Comment: Thank you Mohammad, the name of the key pubMessages is changed dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on this kind of search, like so:

```
$array = array(
            'pubMessages' => array (
                0 => array (
                    'msg' => 'Not bad',
                    'type' => 'warning'
                ),
                1 => array (
                    'msg' => 'Bad',
                    'type' => 'error'
                )
            )
        );

// array_search() will return false. It is not how 
// array_search() works on a multi-dimensional array
// $key = array_search('error',$array);

function findError($a) {
    return ($a['type'] != 'error');
}

// deal with "unknown" first index / key name issue
$idx = array_keys($array)[0];
$array[$idx] = array_filter($array[$idx],"findError");

var_dump($array);
exit;
```

And the output will be:

```
array(1) {
    ["pubMessages"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
             ["msg"]=> string(7) "Not bad"
             ["type"]=> string(7) "warning"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Added a fix for the unknown key / index issue

Comment: IMHO this is probably the way to go.

Comment: This solution doesn't work because **The key name of the array pubMessages is changed every time**

Comment: @Mohammad : fixed the issue, which I would have thought the OP could have solved them self.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `foreach()` over the whole array to pick up any elements.

The main problem is that your just saying

```
$key = array_search('error', $array);
```

This won't look through all sub-arrays etc. to find the value, just the top level.  As the error is in the `type` column of the array, you would have to extract that column and search in this array instead.  You can use `array_column()` to pick out the data.

```
foreach ( $array as &$subarray ) {
    $key = array_search('error', array_column($subarray, "type"));
    unset($subarray[$key]);
}
```